# Nested XML : How to show, data present in nested XML on HTML page, dynamically

Tags: c#, html, xml, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

**Requirement**:
Users can provide **any XML file**(along with XSD file, which contains the schema of the XML file) having data. I need to show the 'data preview' on the asp.net core website and also need to save Schema of the XML in a hierarchical structure in the database(save all the fields present in the XML in DB table).

**Current approach**:
In asp.net core website I have a Controller and corresponding Action for the same.
On View.cshtml I have two 'file' controls to get the 'XML file' and 'XSD file' from user.

Example of XSD file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="PM">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Employee_Level1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Id" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Company" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Gender" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Email" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Account">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BankName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AccountNo" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Payment_Level1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Company" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PaymentNo" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Currency" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Amount" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Attribute">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AttributeName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AttributeContent" type="xs:decimal" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PaidPayment_Level1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Company" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PaymentNo" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Currency" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Amount" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Attribute">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AttributeName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AttributeContent" type="xs:decimal" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Corresponding to this XSD file the XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootTop xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Employee_Level1>
        <Id>GS1</Id>
        <Company>Apple</Company>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <Email>Apple@Apple.com</Email>
        <Account>
            <BankName>Axis</BankName>
            <AccountNo>4235</AccountNo>
        </Account>
    </Employee_Level1>
    <Employee_Level1>
        <Id>GS2</Id>
        <Company>Amazone</Company>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <Email>Amazone@Amazone.com</Email>
        <Account>
            <BankName>HDFC</BankName>
            <AccountNo>123</AccountNo>
        </Account>
    </Employee_Level1>
    
    <Payment_Level1>
        <Company>Apple</Company>
        <PaymentNo>1813424</PaymentNo>
        <Currency>RS</Currency>
        <Amount>60.15</Amount>
        <Attribute>
            <AttributeName>Discount</AttributeName>
            <AttributeContent>15</AttributeContent>
        </Attribute>
    </Payment_Level1>
    <Payment_Level1>
        <Company>Amazone</Company>
        <PaymentNo>7643</PaymentNo>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Amount>17849.15</Amount>
        <Attribute>
            <AttributeName>Discount</AttributeName>
            <AttributeContent>12</AttributeContent>
        </Attribute>
    </Payment_Level1>
    
    <PaidPayment_Level1>
        <Company>Apple</Company>
        <PaymentNo>41</PaymentNo>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Amount>17849.15</Amount>
        <Attribute>
            <AttributeName>Discount</AttributeName>
            <AttributeContent>13</AttributeContent>
        </Attribute>
    </PaidPayment_Level1>
    <PaidPayment_Level1>
        <Company>Amazone</Company>
        <PaymentNo>56</PaymentNo>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Amount>68.15</Amount>
        <Attribute>
            <AttributeName>Discount</AttributeName>
            <AttributeContent>13</AttributeContent>
        </Attribute>
    </PaidPayment_Level1>
    
    <PaidPayment_Level1>
        <Company>EMM-NL</Company>
        <PaymentNo>1813424</PaymentNo>
        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
        <Amount>17849.15</Amount>
        <Attribute>
            <AttributeName>Discount</AttributeName>
            <AttributeContent>1515</AttributeContent>
        </Attribute>
    </PaidPayment_Level1>
</RootTop>
```

I am reading data from the XML file in c# using the following code and loading data/schema in DataSet.

```
 public static DataSet CreateDataTableFromXmlFile(byte[] xsdFileContent, byte[] xmlFileContent)
 {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.ReadXmlSchema(new MemoryStream(xsdFileContent));

     foreach (DataTable tab in ds.Tables)
     {
        tab.BeginLoadData();
     }
     ds.ReadXml(new MemoryStream(xmlFileContent));
     foreach (DataTable tab in ds.Tables)
     {
        tab.EndLoadData();
     }
            
      return ds;
}
```

Once data is in the dataset, we have all the data present in the form of tables.

Showing the data on the UI using code

```
<div>
       @foreach (DataTable table in Model.DtSourcePreview.Tables)
       {
           @CreateTableChild(table);
       }
</div>

@functions
{
   public string CreateTableChild(DataTable table)
   {
       <table class="table mb-0">
           <thead>
               <tr>
               @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
               {
                  <th scope="col">@col.ColumnName</th>
               }
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               @foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
               {
                   <tr>
                   @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                   {
                        <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                   }
                   </tr>
                }
             </tbody>
        </table>
        return "";
    }
}
```

using this cshtml code, I can show all the tables on UI but the data is not being shown in hierarchical order.  e.g the table of Account holds all the accounts(of all employees), but **we need to show the accounts below each corresponding Employee.**
**How can we achieve this?**

**How to get which table is on which level in the XML?**

More Info:

1. the DataTable in DataSet also contains the relationships, dataTable.ChildRelations
2. A new column automatically gets added in parent and child tables for relationships. **How can we distinguish between the automatically added column and original columns?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve it using following code

```
 @foreach (DataTable table in Model.DtSourcePreview.Tables)
                          {
                              if (IsParent(Model.DtSourcePreview, table))
                              {
                                  @CreateTableChild(Model.DtSourcePreview, table);
                              }
                         }
```

The Method is

```
 public bool IsParent(DataSet dataSet, DataTable dataTable)
            {
                bool isParent = true;

                if (dataSet.Relations.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var abc in dataSet.Relations)
                    {
                        if (((DataRelation)abc).ChildTable.TableName == dataTable.TableName)
                        {
                            isParent = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    isParent = true;
                }

                return isParent;
            }
```